# How can I change attribute of parentViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi I have an navigation bar based application which has root view controller which push one table view.I want to choose a value from it and change one cell's textlabel.text.But i can not get back the value?I tried to make nsstring as an variable in rootviewcontroller so i change it but i can not acces that in secondviewcontroller.

and it does not accept `self.navigationcontroller.parentviewcontroller.myTableview` it says that uiview controller does not have myTableview...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not let the pushed view controller request the information it needs, unless it is requested from a shared singleton.

The root view controller already knows how to create and push the second view controller onto the navigation stack. This is the correct place to add more required information. Probably with something like this *(I make the assumption that the root view controller is a `UITableViewController`)*:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip;
{
    UIViewController* vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithRequiredString:
                                 self.someStateString] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                         animated:YES];
}
```

This way `MyViewController` would not need to be changed if circumstances changes. For example if the app is made into a universal iPhone/iPad app, and the view controller should not be pushed, but rather set as the right side detail view of a `UISplitViewController`. This would be the only change needed:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip;
{
    UIViewController* vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithRequiredString:
                                 self.someStateString] autorelease];
    if ([self isPad]) {
        NSArray* vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self, vc, nil]; 
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = vcs;
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                             animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You need to tell the compiler the complete type of "parentViewController"

```
[(YourViewControllerClass*) (self.navigationcontroller.parentviewcontroller) myTableView]
```

2 - `parentViewController` is not the previous view controller on the navigationcontroller stack. Use the `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller. It contains a list of view controllers on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a NSString in the app delegate and pass the value using the app delegate variable

Answer (score 0):

You could make a property for the `myTableView` variable like so:

Header File:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* myTableView;
```

Implementation File:

```
@synthesize myTableView;
```

Then you should be able to refer to `myTableView` in your second class by using:

```
((MyViewController*)self.navigationController.parentViewController)).myTableView ...
```

EDIT: I tried to fit this in a comment, but it was getting quite long...

@Peylo: So your parents had intercourse one day and they knew about you inside of the womb. Then you came out, and you learned about them. Your family was a circular reference and nothing bad has come of it.

Circular references are contained all over the place in programming. Consider a `ViewController` which can refer to it's `View` which can then refer back to it's `ViewController`, but also it's child `Views`, which can refer to their parent, the `View`, but also refer to their children, etc. etc. ad infinitum. That's essentially what delegates are, a way for an object to refer back to some other (possibly unknown) type of object. I could hav easily encouraged the OP to use a protocol, which had crossed  my mind, but I preferred this solution as a quick and dirty method to achieve the desired result.

As has been [pointed out](http://coliveira.net/software/make-it-work-first-then-make-it-better/) [numerous times](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2010/01/26/correct-beautiful-fast-in-that-order/) [in the past](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast), you should first make your application *work*. It doesn't matter how "good", "fast", etc. your code is if it doesn't perform the correct operations.

In theory, you should spend the majority of your time architecting your application with a smaller amount of time allotted to developing the software. In practice, it almost never works this way. In a professional environment, you must be able to justify your employment, which sometimes means erring on the side of productivity instead of "correct" code.

Perhaps you come from a perfect world where you are always able to perfectly architect your software and never get handed a pile of crap code developed by a stoner, in which case I wish we could all be as lucky as you. But the [truth still remains](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/the-long-dismal-history-of-software-project-failure.html) that most software is abandoned before it is completed, or is over budget or not on time.

Comment: Use of a typecast is a clear tell sign of a bad design. What you have done is introduced a circular dependency. The root view controller knows about the child it pushes *(all fine)*, but the pushed view controller also knows about the view controller that pushed it *(this introduces the circular dependency)*. As a extra bad you also introduce assumptions about how a view controller is used into untestable code. What if you want to push the view controller, but present it in a `UIPopoverController` some day?